# Image in flexible layout, centered (or at a fixed %) no matter the width? CSS only. Picture inside

Tags: html, css

[image: Flexible Layouts]

The focus is on the CSS3 icon. The upper image is when the browser width is 480px. The two lower images are when it is at 200px. The lower right image is exactly what I want to achieve, which are summarized in the following conditions.

1. No distortion of the image whatsoever. (That disqualifies the method used on the opera icon.)
2. The **center** of the image must be at a certain % of the container width. In the case of the images, that % is exactly 50%, but it could have been others because I need to animate it.

I was only able to achieve the lower right effect by wrapping the image in a div with 0 width and height, positioned top and left at 50%. Then, the image inside is positioned top and left at -60px (120px is the width and height of the image).

I there an "industry standard" way of doing this that is less complicated?

Also, the images that I'm using there are sprites, so I don't know if that makes it more complicated. The images have already been wrapped by a div tag with overflow: hidden to hide the other sprites.

Comment: use flexbox. IE11+ required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a container. let's say your CSS3 icon has `class="css3icon"`. simply use:

```
.css3icon{
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-60px; /* (half the width of the icon) */
    display:block; /* You should already have this one.. */
}
```

The fact that this is a sprite doesn't make a difference..

You can also use: `margin: 0 auto;` however if you want to animate I recommend going with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, that you want a centered image that's responsive. I'm thinking this won't work because you're using a sprite, but this is what I would do for a normal image:

```
//to center the image
#container {
    //the width can be different but then you'll have to center the container
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
}

#container img {
    display:inline-block;
    //following code makes image resize with browser
    max-width:100%;
    //set this to the smallest size you want to the image to display
    min-width:150px; 
}
```